# How to recover lost changes locally

Tags: github

I have a project on GitHub. I made some changes to it and I wanted to apply `git push` but it showed some error. I googled for solution and someone said to do `git stash` `git pull`, so I did those two. In the end all my changes to the projects on my local machine are lost. It became the same project as on GitHub without all the changes.

Tried `git fsck --lost-found` but didn't work.

Comment: Please include the error you got so we have a hint as to what may be wrong. It is very hard to find your issue without the error code! (on a side note: never run *any* code of which you arn't sure what it does. *always* do your research)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git stash` saves you changes but resets the state to the last commit. To restore the saved (not commited) changes, simply run `git stash apply`. ([Learn more in the docs.](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing))